# Kill a specific listener after the on has been fired

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, dom-events

I have a node service that is running socket.io.

On top of this I have an event emitter to fire out updates based on user context. (e.g. context A has user 1, user 2, user 3, context B has user 4 & user 5)

When a successful connection to the socket has been made an event listener is registered to the context of the user.

```
                myEmitter.on(contextGuid, ()=>{
                    if(!socket.disconnected){
                        getUserListing();
                    }
                });
```

from this, I then fire context events outwards when I need to emit changes that have happened in the user's context group.

So the issue I have is more of a housekeeping problem. Is there a way to kill a specific listener on the emitter as they are all named the same thing (context guid) as I am currently spawning many listeners for each socket.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to kill a listener just use the same sintax about the listener initialization but put null in the parameters!

```
myEmitter.on(null);
```

Comment: Wouldnt that kill all of the listeners? I only need to kill a specific one however they are all named the same, cheers!

Comment: The code I wrote will only kill the listener associate with myEmitter variable.  If you have the same listener in more than one object every body still alive without myEmitter